# Display LatLng on TextView when Button Pressed

Tags: android

How to display current location (LatLng) in a textview, when the button is pressed?

I'm using GPS Tracker but it will display the current LatLng in emulator only not on the actual phone. Please take a look at some of my code.

This is my .jave file:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Objects;

public class GPSTracker  extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; // 1 minute
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = Objects.requireNonNull(locationManager)
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }
    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }
    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it.

```
 case  R.id.btn_service_get_current:
            gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

            if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                double lat = gps.getLatitude();
                double lng = gps.getLongitude();

                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String latit = String.format("%.4f",lat);
                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String longit= String.format("%.4f",lng);
                lati.setText(latit);
                longi.setText(longit);

            }else{
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Notice!");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Cannot get your current location, please turn on your device location");
                alertDialog.show();
            }

            break;
```

If anymore code is needed, let me know.

Comment: @Jigangsu read the question again

Comment: @Jigangsu nothing happens on actual phone

Comment: if you are testing on above marshmallow android device you need add runtime permission

`android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

Comment: yes Im using marshmallow @sukhbir , and how can I do that?

Comment: please see below answer to add `permissions` at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For runtime `permissions`, In `onCreate()` of your `Activity` call below method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkRunTimePermission();
}

  private void checkRunTimePermission() {
    String[] permissionArrays = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(permissionArrays, 11111);
    } else {
        // if already permition granted
        // PUT YOUR ACTION (Like Open cemara etc..)
    }
}
```

To Check permission is granted or not `override` this method in `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    boolean openActivityOnce = true;
    boolean openDialogOnce = true;
    if (requestCode == 11111) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];

       boolean isPermitted = grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // user rejected the permission
                boolean showRationale = false;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    showRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission);
                }
                if (!showRationale) {
                    //execute when 'never Ask Again' tick and permission dialog not show
                } else {

                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: where is that isPermitted?

Comment: this is  `boolean variable ` You `initialize` this as `boolean isPermitted;`

Comment: @sukbir - I already figure it now, I use the same checking in getting current location in map, thanks to you